# Compiled package installation issues since upgrading R from version 3 to 4.0.3 with Big Sur v11.1

Tags: r, installation, macos-big-sur

I have been getting a lot of errors when trying to install packages, especially the ones that need compilation, I believe.

For example, I try to install the 'lfe' package, and this is my error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: library not found for -lm
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lfe.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lfe’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lfe’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lfe’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_4/k5fb7b_j5_q0hmn0_qx0l8900000gn/T/RtmpJbG4L3/downloaded_packages’
Error in library(p, character.only = TRUE) : 
  there is no package called ‘lfe’
```

I tried following the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Note-for-Catalina-and-Big-Sur-users), but I am having a hard time following them as written.